# How do Germans pronounce "Willst du auch etwas?"

Tags: pronunciation

When German native speakers say "Willst du auch etwas?", do they pronounce it:

> willst du aufas

listening to a "learning with locals" videos and that's all I hear. Is it right to say it like that (aufas).

Comment: Why only Germans? When you have question about English language do you ask only how people living in England deal with it? German is official language also in Austria, Switzerland, Liechtenstein, Belgium, Luxembourg and parts of France and Italy. And German nativespeakers live in almost all other countries too. The German speaking people in these countries are not Germans and they don't feel German, like Irish or Indian people aren't English and don't feel English or Mexican people aren't Spanish and don't feel Spanish just becaue they speak Spanish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Willst du auch etwas?

is commonly shorted to

> Willst du auch was?

which is commonly shorted to

> Willst(e) auch was?

which is commonly shorted to

> Auch was?

If you can't hear the difference between */f/* and */ch/* you have to practice that. The minimal pair is [*auf*](https://de.forvo.com/word/auf/) vs [*auch*](https://de.forvo.com/word/auch/).

Comment: I believe that the ch can disappear in some dialects. I am not sure how much the voicing of w can be reduced.

Comment: ty and thanks @CarstenS as they say only "was" not etwas and the "ch" disappear ( the sound of f and v is close ) so "au was" is what i hear

Comment: "Auch was" is commonly shortened to raising our pointing at the thing and producing a "hm?" Or "hö?" Sound, potentially while nodding the head upwards.

Comment: Astonishing, the pronunciation "aufas" sounds quite natural to me. I think the "ch" of "auch" was not simply dropped, but its voicelessness (the hissing effort which it takes) was transferred to the following "w", turning [v] into [f] -- it would then be a fusion of  "ch-w" into a single sound. To be sure, this is a very reduced pronunciation, neither right nor wrong, but sloppy. You'd better not try to imitate it :) But I think you heard it right, against all expectations.

Comment: I do not know of any dialect where "ch" becomes "f". Those are completely different sounds.

Comment: That's not what I said...

Comment: Of course this is not dialectal. But as a matter of speech tempo and sloppiness, phonetic features of two sounds can get entangled. I am pretty sure I could have produced that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Often people will use "was" instead of "etwas" in spoken German. So in order from most relaxed to most formal, you will hear something that sounds like

```
Willste auchwas
Willstu auchwas
Willstu auch etwas
Wills du auch etwas
Willst du auch etwas
```

Don't use the first four in writing. "Was" instead of "etwas" is acceptable in writing.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Shortening of some words in spoken German**

   German native speakers (not only Germans, but also Austrians, Swiss people, and native speakers from everywhere else) very often shorten the indefinite pronoun [etwas](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/etwas) to the indefinite pronoun [was](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/was) (*Bedeutung #2* on the linked site). They do it especially in colloquial speech, but sometimes also in contexts where speaking in standard German is appropriate. In written German this is much rarer. So, we have this shift in spoken German:

   > Willst du auch etwas? → Willst du auch was?
2. **Speech breaks not always correspond with spaces between written words**

   This phenomenon exists in all languages that use spaces to separate written words. Those spaces mark a border between small meaningful units that we call "words". But spoken language very often doesn't care about such spaces. Otherwise it would have been impossible that in so many languages contractions could have evolved (English: "I am" → "I'm", "it is" → "It's", ... German: "zu dem" → "zum", "für das" → "fürs", ...).
   In your sentence, if you listen really carefully, you will hear even two  omitted speech breaks:

   > willst du → willsdu
   > auch was → auchwas

   But, as I perceive it, the first contraction (willst du → willsdu) is even more intense performed than the second. This is, because "t" and "d" are two very similar sounds, and it's hard to speak a "d" immediately after a "t", so they merge together to either one "t" or one "d" (but only one of them). On the other side, to speak a "w" after "ch" you need to rearrange the interior of your mouth much more, and this needs some time, and so, also in words like *Sti**chw**ort* or *Na**chw**eis,* many people tend to add a short break between *»ch«* and *»w«: Sti**ch-w**ort, Na**ch-w**eis.*
3. **Misinterpretation of an unknown sound**

   What people actually say between *»au«* and *»was«* is not an f-sound, but a German ch-sound. When you come from a language where such ch-sounds do not exists (like English, that doesn't have those sounds), you very likely will interpret them as something else, and an f-sound is one possibility to misinterpret the sound. Arab and Russian native speakers will have no troubles to identify the sound correctly, because it also exists in their languages.